# Dynamic png javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot that after getting data by a fetch call sends it to dicord.
I read the discord documentation but i cant resize images in the embed message.
Is there any way to build the dynamic png whithout passing from a website, so only using nodejs?
If not is there any way to make a cross site fatch call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html#getting-started

Comment: @rez maybe, but i dont really understand how to use it

Comment: If a create a canvas do i make an external image or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Canvas is an image manipulation tool that allows you to modify images with code. So in order to resize an image, you need to upload it from a local directory.

```
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg')

    // This uses the canvas dimensions to stretch the image onto the entire canvas
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Yes, but i have to put some images in it how can i do that?

Comment: You need to have a image inside your folder, then find it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) to resize your image and then add it as an attachment to the embed. You still need to fetch the image in order to do that, though.

Assuming you already have your image (which you can either fetch from an external source or load locally) as a `Buffer` variable named `image`, your code would look like the following:

```js
const sharp = require('sharp')

sharp(image).resize({ width: 100, height: 100 }).toBuffer().then(resizedImage => {
  const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(resizedImage, 'image.png');
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('This embed has a resized image attached to it!')
    .attachFiles(attachment)
    .setImage('attachment://image.png')
  channel.send(embed)
})
```

You can read more about resizing images with sharp [here](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize).